# Bash how to ensure a text file is non-empty but adheres to a certain format?

Tags: bash, unix

This standard check to see if a file is non-empty can be easily broken:

```
if [ -s "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "contains stuff"
else
    echo "empty"
fi
```

Like if I just put a newline in there it will count as something being there. How can I ensure that if something is there it is at least a valid character? I need to ensure the text in a file is in a format like this:

```
test
test
\n
```

and not something like this:

```
\n
\n
```

Comment: *broken*? I don't think so, empty means zero-bytes. And it's unclear why the `\ntest\n` one is incorrect.

Comment: @oguzismail but is there an easy way to not count newlines too?

Comment: Yes. `grep -q '[^[:space:]]' file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
if [ -s "$FILE" ]; then
```

with

```
if grep -q . "$FILE"; then
```

`grep . filename` returns true (exit code 0) if any line in the file matches `.` (which, in regex, means any character).  Newlines aren't matched.  `-q` tells grep to be quiet so `grep -q . filename` performs the same test but silently, producing no output.